# How can I get css pseudo element :checked to work in IE7 + IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, pseudo-element

I'm trying to style selected radio buttons different than non-selected radio butons in IE 7+8. I've tried selectivizer and it fixed the problem, but also created other problems with css background images being set as hidden. Does anyone know of another JS library that will fix the IE pseudo issue?

Comment: you could use .checked and append a class to the checked boxes. See usage here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp

Comment: I have no IE7 or IE8at my disposal, but have you tried the attribute selector? input[checked="checked"] Should work according to http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp provided you have a doctype declared

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried IE9.js ?

- http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/
- http://www.charlescooke.me.uk/web/lab_notes/ie7_script.html
- http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/index.html
- http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/checked.html