# CSS Only Custom Checkbox in IE8

Tags: css, checkbox, radio-button

I found Custom CHECKBOX and RADIO from the [**link**](http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/custom-form-radio-checkbox/) but could not find this working in IE8.

Is there any way we can use below properties working for IE8?

> **:after**
>
> **:before**
>
> .big-radio:checked **+** label:after

Please let me know.

Comment: Try with [selectivizr.js](http://selectivizr.com/) or [ie7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/).

Comment: Thanks @Vucko but this doesn't work with IE8. I have tried both.

Comment: If you want a JS solution (not CSS), use [uniformjs](http://uniformjs.com/). I used it all the time, works on IE8. Includes custom images.

Comment: @Vucko I found this also not working with IE8 in XP.
Screenshot: http://www.crocko.com/B1637E9942D2486D80CA34F64C7E4A2A/uniform_IE8.png

Comment: The link is not working. Are you doing it live or on a localhost ? Can you show me your code ?

Comment: I have just paste the DEMO link from the site into browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ie8 doesn't support `:checked`.
You can add class and rewrite rule like this:

`.big-radio.checked + label:after`

Or try something from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11842991/928516