# Fallback in IE8 for radio buttons

Tags: html, css

This is for a fallback, **not** to use IE hack or get `:checked` element to work as answered in [How can I get css pseudo element :checked to work in IE7 + IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835999/how-can-i-get-css-pseudo-element-checked-to-work-in-ie7-ie8)

I need to remove the styling that I have and do a fallback for IE8 to revert back to standard radio buttons in place.

How could I do this?

```css
body {
  font: 16px Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

/* Hiding Radio */
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

/* switch-canvas */
.switch-canvas {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

label.black {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  color: #222;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input.black[type="radio"]:checked + label.black {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-canvas">
  <input class="black" type="radio" id="female" name="sex" checked="" />
  <label for="female" class="black">Female</label>
  <input class="black" type="radio" id="male" name="sex" />
  <label for="male" class="black">Male</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding the css selectors :checked and :not(:checked) to the checkbox styles. This selector is not recognized by IE8 and earlier so the browser will ignore the styles and not hide the checkbox or display the styles for the label.

In your example you give for instance:

```
         /* Hiding Radio */
         input[type="radio"]:checked, input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) {
           display: none;
         }
         input[type="radio"]:checked + label.black, input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label.black {
           display: inline-block;
           *display: inline;
           zoom: 1;
           font-size: 16px;
           font-weight: bold;
           width: 50%;
           height: 40px;
           color: #222;
           line-height: 40px;
           text-align: center;
           cursor: pointer;
           transition: all 0.3s;
           -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
           -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
           -moz-border-radius: 5px;
           border-radius: 5px;
         }
        input.black[type="radio"]:checked + label.black {
           background-color: #fff;
           color: #000;
           border-radius: 2px;
        }
```

Comment: Fix this: `:not(:checked)`, you've missed the semicolons

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Thanks. Actually it works with :not(checked) as well but not sure if that is part of the official spec.

Comment: What browser are you using? `:checked` is a pseudostate, and `:not()` accepts selector arguments like pseudostates, so if you missed a semicolon it's a tag, not a pseudostate!! (`checked` in CSS means `<checked>` tag in HTML). If you are using a browser that accept this behaviour, please, report the bug to the company, it's not a normal behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, simply if selector is not valid than it selects the checkbox so it worked

Comment: `checked` selector is not valid. Finish. `checked` selector targets a `<checked>` tag that doesn't exist. No more. If it's working is due fallbacks or something similar, or workarounds in browsers to avoid problems. I can't found anything official about it, so it doesn't exists. But it's better if you take care and write valid selector as `:not(:checked)` :)